# Determine a basis for the solution of $x - 3y + z = 0, 2x-6y+z = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Determine a basis for the solution of
>
> $x - 3y + z = 0, 2x-6y+z = 0$

I tried this; 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 1 \\
2 & -6 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Gauss ->

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
only the first column has a pivot, what should i do next?

Comment: Convert back to the equation form, make $x$ as subject, claim the solution is $[x,y,z]$, then substitute.

Comment: @LiChunMin is it $(3, -3 , 0), (-1, 0 ,1) $ ?

Comment: Put in those values for x,y,z, Does it solve the equations?  And note that the matrices you have provided doe not tie out with the equations.

Comment: Your matrix second row is not a representation of the second equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x-3y+z=0\tag 1$$
$$2x-6y+z=0\tag 2$$

$$2 (1)-(2)\implies z =0$$
$$\implies x=3y $$

the set of solutions is span$(3,1,0) $.